# Load Data From Both TXT and XLS Files in powerbulider

Tags: excel, xls, ole, powerbuilder

I am trying to load data from both text and excel files when i click on browse button in a datawindow. I am able to load data from the text file but not from the Excel,xls file.

Here is my Code

```
long    ll_return



IF dwo.Name = "b_browse_meters"   THEN // Browse Button Clicked

ll_return = GetFileOpenName ( "Select Meter File", is_fullname, is_filename, " XLS", &
    " Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls" )

if ll_return < 1 then 
    //MessageBox("Error", "Error selecting meter file...!!!", StopSign!)
    gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX28", "", "", OK!)
    return
end if


dw_datos_ingreso.object.meters_batch_dir[1] = is_fullname

END IF // Browse Button Clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use multiple values for the extension. You have "TXT, XLS". Try passing "" instead.

You don't show the actual line of code that does the data import. The DataWindow does not support importing Excel files. Only tab delimited text, CSV (comma separated values text) and XML formatted text.

Also, please specify the version of PowerBuilder you are using.

Comment: A Function to load the XLS file to input field. Am Using PB7